# c# List of dictionaries except method is slow

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I'm using `.Except` method to get a difference between 2 `List of Dictionaries`.

My dictionary has 22 key,value pairs

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> uatCSVFile

List<Dictionary<string, string>> prodCSVFile

uatCSVFile.Except(prodCSVFile, new DictComparer())
```

I'm getting the exact differences. It works fine for small files but when testing with a 6mb file and it takes 4-5 mins to work.
Please suggest how can I improve the performance?

DictComparer :

```
{
    public bool Equals(Dictionary<string, string> x, Dictionary<string, string> y)
    {
        return (x == y) || (x.Count == y.Count && !x.Except(y).Any());
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Dictionary<string, string> x)
    {
        var ret = 123;

        foreach (var keyValue in x)
        {
            ret = ret + (keyValue.GetHashCode() * 31);                

        }
        return ret;      
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you have two dictionaries and you would like the get the difference between the two? Are those uatCsvFile and prodCsvFile dictionaries? Or did you mean you have two of sth like List<Dictionary<string,string>> and you want the difference between the two lists?

Comment: yes please I have 2 list of dictionaries                      List<Dictionary<string, string>> uatCSVFile
List<Dictionary<string, string>> prodCSVFile    and  I want the difference between them. except gives me exact results..but its very slow

Comment: Use a profiler to determine what is actually slow.

Comment: the comparison is slow.. it takes 5 mins to compare  2 files using except method and file size is 6mb

Comment: @user7436928: Which line of code in the comparison is slow?

Comment: @user7436928 PerfView is a good free performance tool. You can tutorials online. With that tool, you will be able to see what is the bottleneck.

Comment: Just a quick comment: shouldn't it be `ret = ret * 31 + keyValue.GetHashCode();` instead of `ret = ret + (keyValue.GetHashCode() * 31);`?

Comment: Also, what do you do with the result of the `Except`? You do realize it's only an `IEnumerable<>` and not a list, so if you call multiple operations on it, it will do all the work again, right?

Comment: ret = ret * 31 + keyValue.GetHashCode(); instead of ret = ret + (keyValue.GetHashCode() * 31);?  :  it doesn't make any difference and both are same.                    
 
 
Also, what do you do with the result of the Except? You do realize it's only an IEnumerable<> and not a list, so if you call multiple operations on it, it will do all the work again, right?   :  I can't loop the whole collection and compare. except will give the exact differences im looking for .